# Oracle SQL - Calculate the running most-recent value and associated values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table of student test scores, along with the year taken, and the specific test taken, which looks like this:

```
Student ID     Score    Year    TestName  GradeLevel
100001         347      2010    Algebra   8
100001         402      2011    Geometry  9
100001         NA       NA      NA        10
100001         NA       NA      NA        11
100001         525      2014    Calculus  12
```

This sample table only has one Student ID in it, but my actual data obviously has many Student IDs in it.

I'm trying to write a query that will tell me, in each school year, what was each student's score on their most-recently-taken test, which test it was, and what grade level they were in. The output that I want should look like this:

```
StudentID     Year    MostRecentScore  MostRecentTest  MostRecentTestGrade
100001         2010    347              Algebra         8
100001         2011    402              Geometry        9
100001         NA      402              Geometry        9
100001         NA      402              Geometry        9
100001         2014    525              Calculus        12
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
SELECT
    STUDENTID,
    YEARID,
    MAX(Score) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY Year) as "MostRecentScore",
    MAX(TestName) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID ORDER BY Year) as "MostRecentTest",
    MAX(GradeLevel) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentID  ORDER BY Year) as "MostRecentTestGrade"

FROM TEST_SCORES
```

But this is only returning the most recent test and its associated values:

```
StudentID     Year    MostRecentScore  MostRecentTest  MostRecentTestGrade
100001         2010    525              Calculus        12
100001         2011    525              Calculus        12
100001         NA      525              Calculus        12
100001         NA      525              Calculus        12
100001         2014    525              Calculus        12
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know that NA corresonds to a  year between 2011 and 2014?  This seems to be magical information, which makes the question hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

According to your example we can use `gradelevel` to determine order. If so, you could use `lag() ignore nulls`. But to do that, at first, we need to do something with column `gradelevel` which is a bit problematic. I added `gl` which is null when year is null too. The rest is simple:

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ecbb/1)</sup>**

```
select studentid, yearid, 
       nvl(score, lag(score) ignore nulls 
                  over (partition by studentid order by gradelevel)) score,
       nvl(testname, lag(testname) ignore nulls 
                     over (partition by studentid order by gradelevel)) test,
       nvl(gl, lag(gl) ignore nulls 
               over (partition by studentid order by gradelevel)) grade
  from (select ts.*, case when yearid is null then null else gradelevel end gl 
          from test_scores ts)
  order by studentid, gradelevel
```

I assumed that values `NA` are nulls in your data. If they are not you have to use `nullif` at first and probably for numbers like in column `score` use `to_number`. Making column like `score` and `YEAR` as varchars is bad idea.